# "NPM Audit" command reporting issue with a version of a package "NPM Show Version" says I don't have

Tags: visual-studio, npm

I have been alerted to a vulnerability in one of my NPM packages. When I go to investigate this issue, NPM points me to a package and mentions to update to a certain version. When I check the current package version, I'm already above the version It says I need to be. Which command is incorrect, or am I missing something?

```
  PM> npm audit 
 === npm audit security report ===   



                                Manual Review                                 
           Some vulnerabilities require your attention to resolve            

           Visit https://go.npm.me/audit-guide for additional guidance          

 Regular Expression Denial of Service                       

 Package       clean-css                                                    
 Patched in    >=4.1.11                                            
 Dependency of gulp-cssmin [dev]                                         
 Path         gulp-cssmin > clean-css                             
 More info  https://npmjs.com/advisories/785                            

    found 1 low severity vulnerability in 6866 scanned packages
    1 vulnerability requires manual review. See the full report for details.

 PM> npm show clean-css version    
    4.2.3
```

Comment: Could you remove the ANSI codes when pasting? Also please show the specific version of clean-css installed *for gulp-cssmin*, e.g. from the package-lock.json file.

Comment: I've updated the text to remove ANSI. And by looking at the version in the package.lock file for gulp-cssmin, I can see its at a lower version (3.4.28)

Comment: Can you upgrade gulp-cssmin then? According to the package file in GitHub its latest version uses clean-css ~4.2.1, which doesn't have that problem.

Comment: I'm already on the latest version.  gulp-cssmin@0.2.0

Comment: A PR got merged in November to fix that: https://github.com/pdehaan/gulp-cssmin/commit/bb368ecf75d0d620e8d6766ddba9987857ff5040. Maybe ask the maintainers to cut a release.

Comment: Yep, nice find. Thanks @jonrsharpe.